# How to display custom error message in a Standard Visuaforce page

Tags: apex

I have a requirement, where I have to catch the error message in an `Opportunity` `Trigger` and have to display it on top of the Standard VF page.

What, I know, we can go for `Sobject.field.addError()` to display the error, but it will appear below the field.

Is there any way where we can show the custom error message in a Standard VF page ?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add the error to SObject (instead of the field) to get it to show up at the top of the page

> Sobject.addError()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd do the same for the *record* as opposed to the field, for example in your Trigger:

```
for(Opportunity oppt : Trigger.new)
{
    try
    {
        // something to cause an error
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        oppt.addError('caught ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```